# VueJS pass default prop without reference to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, reference, vuejs2

I've stumbled upon this situation where I want to pass a prop to a child component that will be the `default` value of the component, but it will only be showed when the initial value is empty.

**Parent Component:**

```html
<multi-line-input v-model="data.something" placeholder="Enter Something" :default="data.something"/>
```

**Child Component**

```js
props: {
  value: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  default: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
},
methods: {
  emitBlur (e) {
    if (!this.value && this.default) {
      this.value = this.default
    }
    this.$emit('blur')
  },
  emitInput () {
    this.$emit('input', this.$el.value)
  }
}
```

So what I am trying to achieve basically, is when the component loads will get the value from `v-model` it will also receive a `default` value that shouldn't change, and only used as a value when the actual value is empty on `blur`

The `default` will have the initial value of `data.something` and it should not change!

I tried to get rid of the reference using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.value))` but it doesn't seem to work either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly, you want this behavior: upon the `blur` event on your `<multi-line-input>` component, if the value of the input is empty, then set the value to a default value which is specified by the parent (through a prop).

First of all, it is an error to do `this.value = ...` in your component. You must not modify props, props pass data from parent to child only, the data passed through props is not yours to modify directly from within the component.

Try something like this:

```js
Vue.component('multi-line-input', {
  template: '<input @blur="onBlur" @input="onInput" :value="value">',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    default: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onBlur() {
      if (!this.value && this.default) {
        this.$emit('input', this.default);
      }
    },
    onInput(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value);
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: null,
    initialUser: null,
  },
  created() {
    // Pretend that I'm pulling this data from some API
    this.user = {
      name: 'Fred',
      email: 'fred@email.com',
      address: '123 Fake St',
    };
    
    // Make a copy of the data for the purpose of assigning the
    // default prop of each input
    this.initialUser = _.cloneDeep(this.user);
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-if="user">
    <multi-line-input v-model="user.name" :default="initialUser.name"></multi-line-input>
    <multi-line-input v-model="user.email" :default="initialUser.email"></multi-line-input>
    <multi-line-input v-model="user.address" :default="initialUser.address"></multi-line-input>
  </template>
</div>
```

Or, if you want the default value to be determined by the component instead of the parent (through a prop), you can do something like this instead:

```js
Vue.component('multi-line-input', {
  template: '<input @blur="onBlur" @input="onInput" :value="value">',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.def = this.value;
  },
  methods: {
    onBlur() {
      if (!this.value && this.def) {
        this.$emit('input', this.def);
      }
    },
    onInput(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value);
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: null,
  },
  created() {
    // Pretend that I'm pulling this data from some API
    this.user = {
      name: 'Fred',
      email: 'fred@email.com',
      address: '123 Fake St',
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-if="user">
    <multi-line-input v-model="user.name"></multi-line-input>
    <multi-line-input v-model="user.email"></multi-line-input>
    <multi-line-input v-model="user.address"></multi-line-input>
  </template>
</div>
```

However I do not recommend the second approach because the child component instance will only every have one default value for its entire lifetime. Vue reuses component instances whenever possible, so it wouldn't work if Vue were to bind it to a different parent component (how/when would it update its own `default` state?).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your insights, true, that was abusive (setting the value manually like that) but the problem is that `Default` should be passed as a variable which is exactly equals to the first value of `value`

Comment: `default` is a prop, so you can set it to the value of a variable if you bind it like this `:default="overviewCopy.header"`, I just didn't do that in my example for brevity.

Comment: doesn't really work since they have the same reference, so when you empty the field `value == '' ` and so does `default`

Comment: `:value="data.something"  :default="data.something"`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that `default` should be set to the initial value of `value`, and should not change, even when `value` does? That's not what you specified in your question.

Comment: If you want to do that, then you're right, you cannot bind both props to the same variable since typing in the input will change both props but you only want the `value` prop to change and not `default`. In that case, you can either (1) bind a different variable to `default` which you have given whatever initial value you want, or (2) get rid of the `default` prop altogether since it needn't be specified by the parent — the child component can figure out what the initial value it was given is and use its own local state to drive that behavior.

Comment: that what I tried to do (second option) but couldn't get the value to be held and keep intact..

Comment: Good suggestion, but when the component is created the value isn't set yet, which means `this.def` is always null

Comment: Hence why I do not recommend that approach and my clarification at the end: *how/when would it update its own `default` state?* If the value isn't set at the component's creation, then you should maintain another data item — say, `initialValue` in addition to `value` — which you can bind like `:default="initialValue"`. Make a deep copy of your data model in the parent component so that you have a copy of the initial values that you can bind to the `default` prop.

Comment: Got it working, thank you, can you edit your answer with the approach where you hardCopy the value and you pass it to the component for other people? thanks man